# Building a graph by keeping it connected

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, graph-theory

Given a finite connected graph $G=(V, E)$, such that $|V|=n$, how many ways can you build a sequence $v_1, v_2, ..., v_n $ (where each $v_i\in V$ and $v_i \ne v_j$ for $i\ne j$), such that for each $i=1,\ldots, n$, the subgraph induced by $\{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_i\}$ is connected?

Given some $\bar{v} \in V$, in how many of the sequences above, is $\bar{v} = v_1$? (What minimum information is needed to answer this question?)